# Count aesthetics differently calculated for R's Date and POSIXct

Tags: r, ggplot2, posixct

I noticed something very strange while working with `Date` and `POSIXct` objects. See the following code:

```
library(tidyverse)
library(Rmisc)

test <- structure(list(
  date = structure(c(
    16863, 16866, 16862, 16743,
    16741, 16819, 16820, 16969, 16896, 16636, 16855, 16715, 16842,
    16899, 16859, 16860, 16827, 16823, 16912, 16878, 16848, 16839,
    16901, 16833, 16896, 16841, 16735, 16800, 16781, 16903
  ), class = "Date"),
  group = structure(c(
    1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 2L,
    2L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 1L,
    2L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L
  ), .Label = c("0", "1"), class = "factor")
), row.names = c(
  NA,
  -30L
), class = c("tbl_df", "tbl", "data.frame"))

test$posix <- as.POSIXct(test$date)

p1 <- ggplot(
  test, 
  aes(x = date, group = group, colour = group, fill = group)
) + 
  stat_density(aes(y = ..count..), alpha = 0.4)

p2 <- ggplot(
  test, 
  aes(x = posix, group = group, colour = group, fill = group)
) + 
  stat_density(aes(y = ..count..), alpha = 0.4)

multiplot(p1, p2)
```

This results in the following plot: see y-axis. (The count < 1 because the sample size is so small.)

[image]

Why would the scales differ on those two graphs when `geom_density` with `..count..` is called? Same when `..density..` is called. The only difference between the two plots is calling upon `x` aesthetics either with `Date` or with `POSIXct`. I'm quite puzzled.

Comment: You should look at output (and then `str()`s of  `density(as.numeric(x$date)) ; density(as.numeric(as.POSIXct(x$date)))` then `?density` and also consider that the area under the curve is 1 but both width and height are important when considering said area.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ah, it was a pretty silly question. Silly me.

```
> as.numeric(test$posix)
 [1] 1456963200 1457222400 1456876800 1446595200 1446422400
 [6] 1453161600 1453248000 1466121600 1459814400 1437350400
[11] 1456272000 1444176000 1455148800 1460073600 1456617600
[16] 1456704000 1453852800 1453507200 1461196800 1458259200
[21] 1455667200 1454889600 1460246400 1454371200 1459814400
[26] 1455062400 1445904000 1451520000 1449878400 1460419200
```

while

```
> as.numeric(test$date)
 [1] 16863 16866 16862 16743 16741 16819 16820 16969 16896 16636
[11] 16855 16715 16842 16899 16859 16860 16827 16823 16912 16878
[21] 16848 16839 16901 16833 16896 16841 16735 16800 16781 16903
```

So as @hrbrmstr said, it is just a matter of unit.

I'll leave this post to serve as a warning, to show that conversion to `POSIXct` class can have unexpected consequences. I was (unnecessarily) trying to use `scale_x_datetime` at the time.